# Load assembly from Roslyn Compilation to new AppDomain

Tags: c#, .net-assembly, roslyn

i'll start with describing the issue. So I'm dynamically creating a .dll with Roslyn Compiler. Later i need to analyze it to make some security checks with reflection. 
If I use following code:

```
...
var assemblyStream = new MemoryStream();
compilation.Emit(assemblyStream);
var assembly = Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoad(assemblyStream.ToArray());
```

It works but I'm unable to unload assembly as this is impossible this way. So i found out I should Create AppDomain, because you can Unload AppDomain with all loaded assemblies. So now my code looks like this:

```
...
var assemblyStream = new MemoryStream();
compilation.Emit(assemblyStream);
var temporaryAppDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("TemporaryAppDomain");
var assembly = temporaryAppDomain.Load(assemblyStream.ToArray());
...
AppDomain.Unload(temporaryAppDomain);
```

And now following line:

> var assembly = temporaryAppDomain.Load(assemblyStream.ToArray());

Throws FileNotFoundException ( Could not load file or assembly ... )

What am I missing ? How can I load my new assembly into temporary AppDomain ?

Comment: Not exactly an answer to your question, but why do you need to analyze code you just generated yourself? Can you not ensure to only generate valid code? If not, can't you use the Roslyn API's to analyze your code?

Comment: @KrisVandermotten i was unclear. Users upload .cs files via our website. I need to build a dll from it so i need to make sure they are not doing anything nasty. I just started analyzing it with roslyn because i can't get above to work, but in this case reflection would be easier and faster i think.

Comment: I'm not sure Reflection would be faster. After all, it requires loading the DLL, which is not required if you use the roslyn API's on the code you are already compiling with roslyn anyway. Secondly, I don't know what you mean with "something nasty", but analyzing with roslyn is certainly much more powerful than with reflection. Finally, whether it is easier depends on previous knowledge, and is in the eye of the beholder.

Comment: Well for roslyn - i will have multiple syntax trees and will have to 'build' semantic model multiple times. I'm inspired now. I'll try to make some benchmarks :)

Comment: You are compiling the source code, so the syntax trees and semantic model need to be built anyway.

Comment: Which file can't be found? What it is will give a lot of hints.